# Combine select method with first method returns error rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've a select statement in a scope into model that looks like:

```
scope :unanswered, -> {includes(:votes).select("posts.*, sum(votes.choice) AS up_vote").order("up_vote ASC").group("votes.id, posts.id").references(:votes)}
```

That's works fine, but when I combined with `first` method, as: `Model.unanswered.first`, I had an error with SQL.

SQL generated by Rails following:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "posts"."id", up_vote AS alias_0 FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."post_id" = "posts"."id" WHERE "posts"."type" IN ('Model') GROUP BY votes.id, posts.id  ORDER BY up_vote ASC LIMIT 1
```

The error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "up_vote" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "posts"."id", up_vote AS alias_0 FROM "post...
```

I've use `(PostgreSQL) 9.1.12`.

is It a Rails bug or not?

Scheme table:

```
create_table "votes", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "post_id"
  t.integer  "choice"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: well not really. it's telling you that the column up_vote does not exist in your table

Comment: can you show your table schema

Comment: Above I added my vote scheme.

Comment: your votes table does not contain an up_vote column.

Comment: Yes, haven't up_vote column, it's used combining with sum clauses describe on my scope, you can see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it as

```
Model.unanswered[0]
```

instead of Model.unanswered.first

When you say `Model.unanswered.first` internally rails activerecord adds `LIMIT 1` to your query and it fails to find the alias `up_vote` misinterpreting it as a column name.

When you use `Model.unanswered[0]` then the query is fired correctly(without adding any `LIMIT 1`) and as the return result is an array you pull the first element by specifying index zero i.e., `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, work for me! But internally, do you think it should work?

Comment: Glad to help :). I lost you here `But internally, do you think it should work`? Could you explain.

Comment: I can explain, should Rails do it by itself? IMO, use Model.unanswered[0] I don't like, I think should work with Model.unanswered.first. it isn't a bug but a featured for Rails, don't you think that?

Comment: @KirtiThorat, it's bad decision, cause `Model.unanswered[0]` is the same as `Model.unanswered.to_a[0]`. You will load the whole table, convert it to array and then use only one record.

Answer (score 0):

Check the difference between different ways to use eager loading in rails. http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

In your case `includes` uses `eager_load` which removes `sum(...)` from `select`. Try to use `preload` instead of `includes`.

```
scope :unanswered, -> {joins(:votes).select("posts.*, sum(votes.choice) AS up_vote").order("up_vote ASC").group("votes.id, posts.id").preload(:votes)}
```